# Can not hit API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a 2 tier architecture. In the main project I have Webforms application and in sub project I have an ASP.NET Core Web API in which I have API endpoints.

This is the screenshot of my file structure:

[image]

This is my endpoint:

[image]

This is where I am testing it:

[image]

I can not get to the API please help.

Comment: this might not solve it, but just to clarify - why are you using 'https'? Do you have an SSL cert configured for local environment? From the error you are getting there is something wrong with the api route. Please share more details like controller name and the route configured for the controller.

Comment: What is the name of the Controller or what route did you specify as the API you're trying to call doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The web api's default support model binder type is for json not for formadata, if you want to use formdata, I suggest you could add the [FromForm] attribute.

The details method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WebUsersController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult LoginUser([FromForm]Users user) {


        return Ok("aa");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]